# IF statement with 3 variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1 can be filled in with whole number values

I want that if Cell A1 is less than 10 then B1 says'<10'
I want that if Cell A1 is between 10 and 25 then B1 says'10-25'
I want that if Cell A1 is more than 25 then B1 says'>25'

At the moment I cannot get an IF statement to run all 3 statements in the same formula.

I will be happy to use normal formulas or even VBA for this to work.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a nested IF

```
=IF(A1<10,"<10",IF(A1<=25,"10-25",">25"))
```

Comment: i have edit your answer, the question ask to test `A1` not `B1`